# how do i access the session variables in the pages

Tags: atk4

how do i access the session variables in the pages in agile toolkit. i am using $this->getUser() but it is not working

Answer (score 3):

In agile toolkit each object can register session variables. This is done to allow you to have multiple objects work indecently and not conflict.

Basic functions are:

```
$o->memorize('handle',123);

$o->recall('handle');

$o->forget('handle');
```

If you intentionally wish to share data, then you can use

```
$o->api->memorize('my_global_var',123);
```

Since you mentioned about User ID, then authorization object handles its own variables. Similarly it uses memorize/recall to manipulate auth data settings, but you can get the information like this:

```
$user_id = $o->api->auth->get('id');
```

When $auth->check() is performed, all fields returning by the query are saved. If you wish to add more fields, then perform

```
$auth->dq->field('extrainfo');
```

and this field will be selected by DSQL and stored in session too for further retrieval by `$auth->get('extrainfo')`

To create getUser function, typically you would define this in API:

```
function getUser(){
    return $this->add('Model_User')->loadData($this->auth->get('id'));
}
```

and use `$this->api->getUser()` to retrieve the data.

Comment: Dont forget to mark Roman's answer as the right one by clicking the tick in the left margin